# How to use literal value as generic parameter in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to hint a `bytes` object with fixed length:

```py
data: FixedLengthBytes[100]
```

But mypy complains: `Invalid type: try using Literal[100] instead?`. Because it requires the value between brackets to be a type, not int literal.

It might be relevant to `typing.Annotated` or `types.GenericAlias`. Following code works perfect at run-time, but cannot pass type check:

```py
class FixedLengthBytes:
    def __class_getitem__(cls, length: int) -> Type[bytes]:
        return Annotated[bytes, FixedLength(length)]
```

---

This specific demand can be workarounded by directly using `Annotated`, but it's verbose and less encapsulated.

```py
data: Annotated[bytes, FixedLength(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to imply with the type is what's done in *Design-by-contract*: you set pre-conditions and/or post-conditions, and it's up to the library to check them. There are some libraries to do this, such as [`crosshair`](https://github.com/pschanely/CrossHair) and [`deal`](https://deal.readthedocs.io/). Look at the following example, which works with `crosshair`:

```py
from typing import List

def duplicate_list(a: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """
    pre: len(a) > 1
    post: len(__return__) == len(a) * 2
    """
    return a
```

This is ensuring that the list to duplicate is not empty, and that the resulting list has twice the size.

If you really want to do these checks using the type systems, then try [`refined`](https://github.com/espetro/refined), which is built upon the concept of *Refinement Types*:

```py
from refined import refined, NonEmptyList
from typing import Generator

@refined
def duplicate_list(a: NonEmptyList[int]) -> NonEmptyList[int]:
  return a
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not looking for a library to check the constraint. I hint it for binary packaging and for my purpose `FixedLengthBytes[100]` works well. The problem is, this format is incompatible with mypy. I cannot tell mypy to ignore the constraint and treat it as ordinary `bytes`.

Comment: I guess then that you can get it to work with typeguards (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/). It works with mypy, and this way you can be sure that a `bytes` object has a fixed length of 100. As a disadvantage, you need to add an `if`statement; however, the object will still be treated as `bytes`.